# convert .net password hasing function to PHP

Tags: php, .net, encryption

I have this function in .net

```
public static byte[] EncryptPassword(string username, string pwd, string salt)
{
    string toHash = username + salt + pwd;

    UTF8Encoding textConverter = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] passBytes = textConverter.GetBytes(toHash);
    byte[] thePassword = new SHA384Managed().ComputeHash(passBytes);

    return thePassword;
}
```

and trying to convert it into php

```
function EncryptPassword($username, $pwd, $salt)
{
    $hash = $username.$salt.$pwd;
    return hash('sha384',$hash);
}
```

but I m unable to get the same password hash,any help ?

Comment: edit the parameter name , the parameter is not the problem.

Comment: Your code works for me. The result of php `hash` is an hex string. With "username", "salt", "password", I get the following for both sides: 1E7C24B5DD83076B40BA4A5833962E5749563678B46B4F076C25FD337D62DD76542C3F2CAFD703F67D41B8CBC5D39FD7.

Answer (score 3):

Well you're using `$password` inside the function, but passing `$pwd` as an argument.